# Spring + Thymeleaf - Call a function using received parameter

Tags: spring, parameters, thymeleaf

I have a table filled with a List of String that I receive from a controller, and then I want to put a button for each one to call to another function and get some objects related with that string.

```
<tbody th:each="titulo : ${listaColecciones}">
    <tr>
        <th th:utext="${titulo}"></th>
        <th>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="#" th:action="@{/twittercontrolador/recuperarColeccion}" th:object="${textocoleccion}" th:value="${titulo}" method="post">        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Filtrar">Recuperar coleccion</button>
        </form>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But it seems not to work, it doesn't get the ${titulo} as a parameter for the function

Edit: Here I have a picture of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

As you can see, I get a List (Thre're database table names) in the controller from a method1, and I pass that list to the view. 
There, I'm trying to put a table with 2 columns, first is the string/table name, and second is a button to call a second method which will return the objects in that table.

So, as you may suppose, the `<tbody th:each="titulo : ${listaColecciones}">`is the list of database table names.

```
<th th:utext="${titulo}"></th>
```

The names to know which table are you getting from the database

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="#" th:action="@{/twittercontrolador/recuperarColeccion}" th:object="${textocoleccion}" th:value="${titulo}" method="post">      
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Filtrar">Recuperar coleccion</button>
        </form>
```

And here is where I'm getting the problems, the button. `th:action="@{/twittercontrolador/recuperarColeccion}"` is the second method in the controller and I don't know how to pass it the string (`${titulo}`) as a parameter for it.

Note that `th:object="${textocoleccion}"`is the name of the string I will receive in the second method but I can not set it to the value of the strings.

Comment: what do you mean with "function"? Maybe you can edit you question and show us the rendered output and the output you want (of the relevant part).

Comment: Just edited my question, I think now it's a little more understandable, thank you.

Comment: As specified int the link `th:object` is used for form-beans. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#handling-the-command-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who may have the same problem, this works for me:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="#" th:action="@{/twittercontrolador/recuperarColeccion}" th:object="${textocoleccion}" method="post" >      
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="textocoleccion" name="textocoleccion" th:value="${titulo}">RECUPERAR</button>
                        </form>
```

I guess the key is to use id and name tags :D

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass informations about the button you have clicked, then you should use `input` or `button` as tag and (that's important) a `name` and `value` attribute.

```
<input type="submit" name="somePostParamName" th:value="${titulo}" />
```